# Problems with Charting Display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having problems getting pie charts to display in my views correctly.  With the code below, I have confirmed that bytes are being successfully written to the model and passed to the view.  I have even confirmed that I can save the pie chart to a PNG file within a directory from the view, but every time I attempt to display the pie chart in the browser, no image is displayed.

You will see that I'm using an Index view with a Partial view for the Pie Chart.  The plan is to present multiple partial views into the Index view.

I'm hoping someone can help me get past this.  Thanks in advance.

Model:

```
public byte[] PieChartBytes { get; set; }

public class StatsForPieChart
{
    public string dest { get; set; }
    public long recordCount { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult _DisplayPieChart (model.ViewModel model)
{
    ArrayList xSeriesList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList ySeriesList = new ArrayList();
    foreach (var item in model.statsforPieChart)
    {
        xSeriesList.Add(item.dest);
        sSeriesList.Add(item.recordCount);
    }
    model.PieChartBytes = new Chart(width:800, height:600, theme: ChartThem.Blue)
        .AddTitle("Title")
        .AddLegend()
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Name",
            chartType: "Pie",
            xValue: xSeriesList,
            yValues: ySeriesList)
        .GetBytes("png");
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Index View:

```
Html.RenderAction("_DisplayPieChart", new { model = Model });
```

Pie Chart View:

```
@{
    //the "Save" code is only used to prove the file bytes have been successfully passed and the image is present in the view:
    string sImagePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "Content\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString + ".png"
    WebImage myImage = new WebImage(Model.PieChartBytes);
    myImage.Save(sImagePath);
}
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="@sImagePath" /> //works in debug mode, but gets blocked on web server - not desired solution.
    <img src="@myImage" />  //desired solution, but produces no image.
</div>
```

Comment: Two notes: 1) I don't see where you add a ChartArea which is the area where the data are displayed. 2) X-values for Pie charts are meaningless.

Comment: Can you open that png on the Browser?

Comment: <img src="@myImage />" Those quotes don't match up.

Comment: Sorry, I fat-fingered the quotes.  It's fixed now in the post.  No, I can't open the image in the browser.

Comment: Isn't chart area used with System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting?  In this example, I'm using System.Web.Helpers.  I tried both approaches, but it seems that ASP.NET MVC recommends Helpers and that DataVisualization is more for web forms (based on what I've read).

Comment: Ah, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the image is just a string of bytes and not a file stored on a server anywhere, you need to prefix the bytes like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@myImage" />
```

This is called a Data URL or Data URI

Additionally, though, I'm not sure you need to use WebImage here. You're already calling GetBytes() on the Chart object. That should return the bytes that you can use to display the image:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Model.PieChartBytes" />
```

Based on @Anonymous3521's comment, this code worked:

Controller:

```
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PieChartBytes); 
var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64);
```

View:

```
<img src="@imgSrc" />
```

Comment: This led my down the right path.  I couldn't get that exact code to work, but I used the following: var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PieChartBytes); var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64); <img src="@imgSrc" />

Comment: Nice. I'll update my answer with your solution for future readers.